# illegal start of expression in using goto statement in java

Tags: java, goto

> I am trying to use goto statement to restart a player's turn but its
> not working.

```
if(spaceCheck(arr))
            {
            crack:
                System.out.println("Player "+player+"'s Turn:");
                System.out.print("Row : ");
                row=s.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Column : ");
                column=s.nextInt();

                if(indexValidate(arr,row,column))
                    {
                        arr[row][column]=player;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        goto crack;
                    }
```

Comment: do not use `goto`... poor programming choice. Instead, use a loop (like `while(spaceCheck(arr)){...}`)

Comment: There is no goto statement in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`goto` is not a part of Java.  Perhaps you were thinking of another language.

As blurfus pointed out, even in languages that allow `goto`, you shouldn’t use it.  It’s not good programming, because it encourages a lack of structure and “spaghetti code.”

Use a loop instead:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Player "+player+"'s Turn:");
    System.out.print("Row : ");
    row=s.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Column : ");
    column=s.nextInt();

    if(indexValidate(arr,row,column)) {
        arr[row][column]=player;
        break;  // terminate while loop
    }
}
```